# Can I Create a Macro Name from a Macro Variable

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I would like to send a set of values into a macro using the INTO function. I do this all the time. However, I would like to the same thing for three different tables and I want to create the INTO macro name with a macro variable that I pass in.  Can this be done?  It's not working for me. Perhaps I need a preceding command before the macro name to compile it first?  Essentially, I want three macro stores to be created: IPCOLS with values from IP_DENOMINATORS, LTCOLS with values from LT_DENOMINATORS, and OTCOLS with values from OT_DENOMINATORS.

```
Proc Sql noprint;
%macro SUBST() / parmbuff; 
%let i=1;
%let FT=%scan(%bquote(&SYSPBUFF),1);  

%do %while (&FT^=); 
Select DISTINCT STATE into :&FT.COLS separated by ','
from &FT._DENOMINATORS;
      %let i=%eval(&I+1);  
      %let FT=%scan(%bquote(&SYSPBUFF),&I);
      %end;
%mend SUBST;
%SUBST(IP,LT,OT);
Quit;
%Put &&FT.COLS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that your are not trying to reference the macro variable you created. The macro variables will be named IPCOLS, LTCOLS and OPCOLS.

The main issue is that the macro variable(s) might not exist after the macro ends since you created them while the macro was running.

Make sure that the macro variable you are creating is not made local to the macro. When you reference a macro variable while running a macro it first uses the existing macro variable with that name. If none exists then it makes a new one in the local symbol table for the macro. When the macro finishes the local symbol table is gone. You can use the `%symexist()` function to check if a macro variable already exists or not. If there isn't one you can create a GLOBAL macro variable that will survive past the end of the macro execution.

First thing is don't define the macro in the middle of your other code.  Define it first and then use it. That way your code is much easier to read/edit/debug.  Depending on how you plan to use it you might even want to have the macro generate the PROC SQL and QUIT statements.

Also there is no need to use PARMBUFF option to pass in a list of values.  Just don't use commas between the values.  Use space or some other character.  (Note that you probably don't want the commas in the values of the macro variables you are creating either, but that depends on what STATE is and how you plan to use those macro variables.)

```
%macro subst(list);
%local i prefix mvar;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));
  %let prefix=%scan(&list,&i,%str( ));
  %let mvar=&prefix.cols;
  %if not %symexist(&mvar) %then %global &mvar;
select DISTINCT STATE
  into :&mvar separated by ','
  from &prefix._DENOMINATORS
;
%end;
%mend subst;

proc sql noprint;
%SUBST(IP LT OT);
quit;
%put &=IPCOLS;
%put &=LTCOLS;
%put &=OTCOLS;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, would you be able to elaborate on the differences between the 3 macro options.  You mentioned "Also there is no need to use PARMBUFF option to pass in a list of values."  That makes me wonder which method is best and why.  Your suggested option (above) works as does the other answer provided to this post. And, although it didn't work for this example, I often use the parmbuff macro in my post to pass values through.  So between the 3 options, is one better?  And if so, why?  Are there differences in efficiency, compilation, cleaner coding, etc?

Comment: The PARMBUFF option might be useful in a situation where you want to accept any text given to the macro.  The one place I still use it is in a command line macro that executes an RCS check in that takes the rest of the command line as the comment.  But if you are passing in a list of values it is MUCH easier to call (and parse) if you use something other than comma as the delimiter between values.  I think the place where people think they might need it is if the value to passed might start with `name=`.  But in that case just call the parameter by name. `mvar=name=xx`.

Comment: Excellent information, thank you very much.  I will try to update some of my programs accordingly.  The parmbuff works so I wasn't looking at other options of doing the same thing until the issue came up that prompted me to make this post in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below formulation instead. A few changes were made:

1. The `%subst()` macro is moved outside of PROC SQL so that it can compile first.
2. The `do-while` loop is converted into a `do i = 1 to n`. The `do-while` loop produced a blank value of `&FT` in the final iteration.
3. All macros created are explicitly made global.

Code:

```
%macro SUBST() / parmbuff; 

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.) ) ); 
        %let ft = %scan(%bquote(&syspbuff.), &i.);
        %global &FT.COLS;

        Select DISTINCT STATE into :&FT.COLS separated by ','
        from &FT._DENOMINATORS;

    %end;
%mend SUBST;

Proc Sql noprint;
    %SUBST(IP,LT,OT);
Quit;

%put IP: &IPCOLS;
%put LT: &LTCOLS;
%put OT: &OTCOLS;
```